# Enthought Canopy Package Manager got stuck on MacOs High Sierra

Tags: python, enthought, package-managers, canopy

I tried to update my python packages by using the feature: `update all` of the Enthought Canopy Package Manager. After I started to update it got frozen at some point. This is what I see:[image: The screen what I see after started the update. It is not changing with time.]

As documentation writes [here](https://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/package_manager.html) in cases when an update is in progress one should not close the Package Manager window.

What should I do in this case. I can't find any solution after some googling.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:

1. Force-close Canopy
2. If you are not already running the current version of Canopy, 2.1.9, then install it.
3. Start Canopy.
4. If you just installed Canopy 2.1.9 in step 2, then accept the startup offer to replace the existing Python environment.
5. Otherwise, from the Tools => Troubleshoot menu, reset the Python environment.
6. In the Package Manager Settings section, add the `lgpl` and `gpl` repos, as described in [this article](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021798791--UnresolvableRequirements-or-Conflicting-requirements-when-installing-or-updating-packages)
7. Update all again.