# Enthought Canopy Package Manager error on MacOs High Sierra

Tags: python, enthought, package-managers, canopy

I have a problem with installing packages via the built in Package Manager of enthought Canopy. I tried to use the "Upgrade all packages", but it failed.

Beforehand, I tried to solve my problem according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987813/enthought-canopy-package-manager-got-stuck-on-macos-high-sierra), but it did not functionating.

The Package Manager returns with the message:

```
Warming up...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-       x86_64/egg/canopy_dashboard/packman/package_action_worker.py", line 52,     in run
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-    x86_64/egg/canopy_dashboard/packman/package_action.py", line 196, in     execute
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-    x86_64/egg/canopy_dashboard/packman/packman.py", line 726, in <lambda>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-    x86_64/egg/canopy_dashboard/packman/packman.py", line 1116, in     _upgrade_all
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-    x86_64/egg/canopy_platform/cpython_packages_manager.py", line 268, in     upgrade_all_packages_prompt
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-    x86_64/egg/canopy_platform/cpython_packages_manager.py", line 334, in     _upgrade_all_packages_prompt
PackageUpgradeAllError: upgrading all packages failed. Details     below: 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-    x86_64/egg/canopy_platform/edm_api.py", line 65, in wrapper
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-    x86_64/egg/canopy_platform/edm_api.py", line 431, in     upgrade_all_packages_command
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-    x86_64/egg/canopy_platform/edm_api.py", line 95, in wrapper
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-    x86_64/egg/canopy_platform/edm_api.py", line 454, in     _upgrade_all_command
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-    x86_64/egg/edm/core/packages_manager.py", line 124, in decorator
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-    x86_64/egg/edm/core/packages_manager.py", line 490, in     upgrade_all_command
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-    x86_64/egg/edm/core/packages_manager.py", line 505, in     _upgrade_all_command
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-    x86_64/egg/edm/core/packages_manager.py", line 774, in     _actions_from_request
UnresolvableRequirements: Unable to satisfy requirements 
Conflicting requirements:
Requirements: 'qt == 5.6.2-1'
    Install command rule (+qt-5.6.2-1)
Requirements: 'pyside == 1.2.2-15' <- 'qt ^= 4.8.7' <- 'qt'
    Can only install one of: (+qt-4.8.7-7 | +qt-5.6.2-1)
Requirements: 'pyside == 1.2.2-15' <- 'shiboken ^= 1.2.2' <- 'qt ^=     4.8.7'
    shiboken-1.2.2-14 requires (+qt-4.8.7-4 | +qt-4.8.7-5 | +qt-    4.8.7-6 | +qt-4.8.7-7 | +qt-4.8.7-9 | +qt-4.8.7-10)
Requirements: 'shiboken == 1.2.2-14'
    Install command rule (+shiboken-1.2.2-14)
```

For me, this screen isn't informative and so I am not able to figure out how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please uninstall pyside, shiboken, and qt, then try again. (Pyside is already installed using qt 4, and this cannot coexist with qt 5 in the same environment.) Alternatively, you could use Canopy's integrated EDM to create a new environment with pyqt 5, so you could still use pyside / qt 4 in your original user environment and use pyqt 5 in your new environment.